# Is the reason of the selection rule: $\Delta l=\pm 1$ because a photon only can change its spin with $1\hbar$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, angular-momentum, atomic-physics, quantum-spin

When an electron jumps to another orbital it has to obey the selection rules. For example it can only jump to an orbital with

$$ \Delta l = \pm 1 $$

In the process it sends out a photon. This photon carries away an angular momentum of $ 1 \hbar $ because of its intrinsic spin. Is thus the reason of the selection rule the amount of angular momentum lost has to equal the intrinsic spin of the photon?

Why is it possible in very rare cases to make a bigger jump? It is not completely 'forbidden'. It is just very improbable.